# How to make DjangoTemplates work recursively

Tags: html, django, templating

I have a template `home.html` which is the view of an app in Django. Now, I've added some templating in the `html` file to allow dynamic generation of HTML. For example I use `{% load static %}` and then `href="{% static "path/to/resources" %}"`. So, when I open the app, after running the server, the path is dynamically created.

Now, the problem is that the static files, that are dynamically loaded, also need to load other static files (and extend a template as well). I thought that DjangoTemplating might be working recursively, and will work on the called file too, but sadly that is not true.

So, what should I do to make sure that all my templating logic is taken into consideration by Django, and is allowed to run?

---

`home.html` snippet:

```
{% load static %}
<area alt="andhra" title="Andhra Pradesh" name="andhra" href="{% static  "personal/pages/andhra.html" %}" shape="poly" ... />
```

`andhra.html` looks something like:

```
{% extends "personal/post.html" %}

{% blockcontent %}
  <style>
   #slider
   {
     width: 80%;
....
<div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
        {% load static %}
        <img class="d-block w-100" src="{% static "personal/images/andhraImages/1911-1915.jpg" %}" alt="First slide">
    </div>
...
{% endblock %}
```

Which wants to extend the template:`post.html` which has `{% blockcontent %}`and `{% endblock %}` in it's body.

The `andhra.html` is not being template-processed. That is, when I open the app `home.html` is loaded correctly, but when I go to `andhra.html` from `home.html`, it isn't processed by DjangoTemplating at all.

Comment: This is really confusing. It doesn't seem to have anything to do with being recursive, though. Static files are static, by definition; that is, they are not dynamic. Why are you trying to use static files for this dynamic content?

Comment: @DanielRoseman Yes. Good point there. So, what do you think I should use?

Comment: Why not a normal view associated with a URL?

Comment: @DanielRoseman Did what you said. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, as [Daniel Roseman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/104349/daniel-roseman) said in the comments, loading the files as a static file won't work. We want django to render them. So, I created a function `state` in my `views.py` as :

```
def state(request,state):
    return render(request,'personal/pages/'+state+'.html')
```

That means it tries to render a file at `templates/personal/pages/<state>.html`. Now my `urls.py` looks like:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('',views.index,name='index'),
    path('<state>',views.state,name="state")
]
```

Note that this belongs to the app `polls`. Now, since the `urls.py` of mysite has `polls/`, thus now the link to these views will be accessible by `localhost:8000/polls/<state>`.

Now at every place I wanted a static link, I made a dynamic one by:

```
href="{% url 'state' 'uttarakhand' %}"
```

where `'state'` is the `name` of the `urlpattern` and `'uttarakhand'` is the input value.